# Validating proxied Java Beans doesn't compare against correct values

Tags: java, cdi, bean-validation

I'm trying to make a [CDI extension](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/extend.html) which will validate a Java object which is bound to configuration values.

```java
public class ExampleConfig {

    @Range(min = 1000, max = 9999)
    private int value;

    @Inject
    public ExampleConfig(@ConfigProperty(name = "value") int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

When I make the above class with the `@Singleton` annotation, it works correctly. On startup the CDI extension validates the class which reads an environment variable called "value".

```
Class: com.example.ExampleConfig
Property: value
Value: 22222
Reason: must be between 1000 and 9999
```

When I replace `@Singleton` with `@ApplicationScoped` instead, when injecting and using this class myself, it works as intended, but in the CDI extension, `javax.validation.Validator` appears to always treat the `value` as 0.

```
Class: com.example.ExampleConfig$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
Property: value
Value: 0
Reason: must be between 1000 and 9999
```

I'm struggling to see why this is the case, is anyone able to provide guidance on how to read the value correctly?

Two things I've been trying to achieve to no avail is:

- Have the extension enforce initialization on startup for respective classes.
- Make the CDI extension wait until the bean has initialized.

The following is how I'm calling `#validate`:

```java
public void afterDeploymentValidation(@Observes AfterDeploymentValidation adv, BeanManager bm) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> allViolations = new HashSet<>();

    for (Class<?> type : types)
    {
        final Object typeImpl = BeanProvider.getContextualReference(bm, type, false);
        Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations = (Set<ConstraintViolation<?>>)(Object)validator.validate(typeImpl);
        allViolations.addAll(violations);
    }

    // Omitted for brevity.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Several things:

- First of all, if all you're trying to do is get Bean Validation working, just put the [Hibernate Validator CDI project](https://search.maven.org/classic/#artifactdetails%7Corg.hibernate.validator%7Chibernate-validator-cdi%7C6.1.6.Final%7Cjar) on your runtime classpath.  Nothing else needed; the end.
- If you're doing something else, you're probably running into the fact that a contextual reference to a bean in a normal scope is a [client proxy](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/3.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-3.0.html#client_proxies).  In less stuffy terms, that means it's a proxy, a shell, a holder—and its "innards" (its referent, the thing it is proxying) is not "inflated" until some method is called on the proxy, like `toString()` or a business method.  I'm guessing that what's happening in your case is the validator is looking for validatable fields directly on the proxy.
- One way to "inflate" a contextual reference is to just call `toString()` on it right away before doing something else.  So just call `typeImpl.toString()` before you do anything else to "inflate" the reference.
- I don't think there's any guarantee that the proxy will somehow magically make the proxied object's fields available to you.  For that, you'll need to get the inner proxied object.  Each CDI implementation does this a little differently, but in Weld [you can get this programmatically with some casting](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.jboss.weld/weld-api/latest/org/jboss/weld/proxy/WeldClientProxy.html).